# Nvidia Drivers in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

I have Nvidia Quadro FX 3500. I install Ubuntu but when I install Nvidia Linux Long Lived Drivers after downloading from Nvidia website, then after restarting my computer, is shuts down the screen. I don't know what to do. I don't have widescreen monitor and I was using 1024 x 768 resolution before. Screen shuts after logo screen. But after installing drivers, graphic card stopped screaming.
What can I do to fix this problem?? Is there any other driver which will be helpful to make graphic card work OK without making too much noise. Or, is there any other option to use the same drivers and see the screen.
[I am using 304.88 Linux X64 drivers.](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/59827/en-us)

While installing Nvidia drivers, I have somehow blacklisted old drivers and I don't know how to remove them from blacklist. Now, my display is on 640x480 resolution. Can anybody help me to solve this problem. Or if you can help me to let me install Nvidia drivers for 1024x768 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You installed the wrong driver for your NVIDIA Quadro FX 3500 graphics card. The driver you installed is for the NVIDIA Quadro 4000 graphics card which has 2GB built-in memory. Your NVIDIA Quadro FX 3500 graphics card has only 256MB built-in memory, so you need to uninstall the NVIDIA 304.88 driver and install the NVIDIA Legacy driver.

1. Uninstall all proprietary NVIDIA drivers from your computer, but don't uninstall the default built-in nouveau driver.
2. Download the NVIDIA Linux Display Driver Version 71.86.15 from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/35627/en-us).
3. Using the `cd` command, change directories to the directory containing the NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-71.86.15-pkg2.run driver that you downloaded from the official NVIDIA website.
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-71.86.15-pkg2.run   
   sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-71.86.15-pkg2.run     
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried running your "ubuntu-driver devices" command and I got this in return. "driver : nvidia-304 - distro non-free recommended". I installed it but same problem. Then I run your given for installing nvidia-173 drivers but it says "Package nvidia-173 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source"

Comment: Edited and updated my answer. The next driver I am suggesting to install is an old Legacy NVIDIA Quadro driver from the official NVIDIA website. There are different drivers for different Quadro cards, so I am not sure that this driver will work either, but I hope it does.

Comment: I am getting this "The Nouveau kernel driver is currently in use by your system.  This driver is incompatible with the NVIDIA driver, and must be disabled before proceeding."

Comment: That's not a good idea. Without the nouveau driver, your computer may not be able to boot at all without reinstalling the OS. I don't think that this answer has fixed anything, so I'm probably going to delete it.

Comment: I am somehow able to go beyond that. Now I have kernel header issue. I went to another post where it says to use this command "sudo apt-get install linux-generic" to install kernel header. But its configuration is a little bit problem.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you're making progress. I don't know how to configure the kernel header, so I still don't think I fixed anything, but you should edit your question and add a description to it of anything that you need to know about, besides what is already there in the original version of the question.

Comment: One last thing, Nvidia asked me to blacklist Nouveau drivers. It said it can create one configuration file for me. Now, I don't know where that file is. Is there anything I can to revoke this? I am using 640x480 resolution right now because of this. Log file was updated so wasn't helpful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am back on my LCD resolution. Sorry for bothering you. This is an old graphic card. I think I should replace it with new one. I am planning to purchase AMD R7 250. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Check in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to see if nouveau is blacklisted in that file. Also take a look at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` . Whatever you did to blacklist nouveau should be in your terminal history. `history n` lists the last n lines of your terminal history where n is an integer number between 1 and 2000.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why are you asking this question.But there are two options:

1.You only have to press the super key and type additional drivers. Then click on the icon of the additional drivers program and scan for drivers. It will automatically show you the available drivers. 
2.Go to the graphics engine website (nvidia.com) and download the driver.

Comment: OP wants to install nvidia driver downloaded from website not from additional drivers,he has blacklisted `nouveau` from terminal